# Что значат эти конструкции в php

Tags: php

1.

```
private static function flatmap(callable $fn, array $array)
        {
            if (empty($array)) {
                return [];
            }
            return array_merge(...array_map($fn, $array));
        }
```

Что значит ... в аргументе функции в данном примере? И где про это почитать можно?

2. `$result = $m ?: $path;`

Корректно ли писать такие конструкции? Могут ли приводить к ошибкам или нежелательным последствиям? В языке с++ такая конструкция вызвала бы ошибку при `$m == true`, т.к. была бы попытка присвоить переменной "ничего". Что в этом случае будет присвоено переменной, значение не поменяется? 
Правильно понимаю, что это одно и тоже,
`$m ? 0 : $result = $path;` ?

3.

```
$reference && $wrapperLink = function (& $linkParam) use ($self, $eventType, $handler, $reference) { .. }
```

Можно ли использовать такие конструкции без опасения возникновении ошибок?
Правильно понимаю, что переменной `$wrapperLink` будет присвоена функция только если `$reference == true` ?
Получается, что на практике вмеcто этой конструкции: `if($soveVar) someFaction();` можно писать так: `$soveVar && someFaction();` ?

Comment: кажется в вашем вопросе не хватает фрагментов кода

Comment: @teran подкорректировал порядок.

Comment: Третий уже аккаунт или четвертый?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ни странно ответы на все ваши вопросы можно найти в документации

> Что значит `...` в аргументе функции в данном примере? И где про это почитать можно?

`...` это  оператор упаковки/распаковки аргументов функции в массив. Употребляется в обе стороны. Строка вашего кода `array_merge(...array_map($fn, $array));`  будет равносильна (условно)

```
$data = array_map($fn, $array);
array_merge($data[0], $data[1], .... $data[N]);
```

то есть каждый элемент массива будет передан в функцию в качестве отдельного аргумента. Можно использовать в обратную сторону `function(...$args){}` при вызове `$func($a, $b)` в качестве аргументов получим массив `$args = [$a, $b]`.

Примеры можно посмотреть в разделе ["Списки аргументов переменной длины"](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php)

> Корректно ли писать такие конструкции?

Вполне корректно, пример данной записи и логика ее работы приведена [в описании тернарного оператора](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

> Начиная с версии PHP 5.3 также стало возможным не писать среднюю часть тернарного оператора. Выражение expr1 ?: expr3 возвращает expr1 если expr1 имеет значение TRUE и expr3 в противном случае.

отсюда следует, что следующее ваше суждение ошибочно.

> Правильно понимаю, что это одно и тоже

Относительно вопроса 3. Тут ваши рассуждения корректны. Как и подавляющее большинство других языков, пхп не использует полное вычисление логических выражений. В целом подобная запись снижает читабельность и  понятность кода, так что решайте сами, стоит ли ее применять. На практике такая форма записи чаще встречается, например, в JS, а не PHP.